# Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to add an AdMob ad to my android application but whenever I'm opening the activity that is supposed to display the ad I get this error:

```
I/Ads(11448): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"kw":[],"preqs":4,"session_id":"17111845472336325405","u_sd":2,"seq_num":"5","slotname":"MYUSERIDHERE","u_w":360,"msid":"com.lazyprogrammer.dartscore","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.0.1","mv":"8011019.com.android.vending","isu":"70069487A7A68D24BEF2581104A73318","cipa":0,"format":"360x50_mb","net":"wi","smart_h":"auto","app_name":"1.android.com.lazyprogrammer.dartscore","hl":"en","smart_w":"full","u_h":613,"carrier":"26203","ptime":225498,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>
E/Ads(11448): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (about:blank:1)
E/Web Console(11448): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined at about:blank:1
I/Ads(11448): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
D/webviewglue(11448): nativeDestroy view: 0x2bc958
I/Ads(11448): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
I/Ads(11448): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
D/webviewglue(11448): nativeDestroy view: 0x5a1850
I/Ads(11448): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

I can't find anything on this problem on google or elsewhere and I don't think I'm doing anything wrong.

Just in case, here is my xml snippet that is supposed to show the ad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    ...

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="MyIDhere"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="70069487A7A68D24BEF2581104A73318" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course I took out all the - I think - unnecessary code for this problem but if it's necessary to see it I'll post it here as well.

I also took out my AdMob UnitID, you probably figured that out but I'm writing this here so that missing UnitId won't be an answer.

My Manifest has the right permissions listed:
    android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
    android.permission.INTERNET

and i also have the AdActivity added with the right configChanges

Comment: From the logs it looks like you are on 6.0.1.  I assume you have all 7 configChanges AdMob specifies if your app runs.  Are you sure your device has connection to the internet?

Comment: Yeah, the device is connected to my home wifi, and here are my configchanges:    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

Comment: hmm, I'm stumped.  Is this device specific?  Does it work on emulators?

Comment: It's the strangest thing. I'm having this problem on my device (Galaxy Nexus) and the emulator AND another device (Galaxy SII). Thanks for your time by the way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this error too and solved by loading the ad in separate thread (in ICS you're not allowed to perform network operation in the main thread)

```
(new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                     Looper.prepare();
                    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: Wow thank you, didnt expect an answer anymore and this was short, straight to the point and fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely not the answer. This did not fix my exact same problem.

Comment: Hasn't fixed mine either. Apparently it's a known issue with certain devices or maybe just 4.0.4 ICS. Same error on my HTC Desire HD. Works fine in the emulator on my stock nexus 7. Tried it both with and without a new thread.

Comment: Admob Mediation was working fine. Started getting this error for about 15 mins. Thread solution did not work. Then error went away on its own. Maybe its an Admob network issue/bug. Device is Android 4.1.1

Comment: I would guess (safely) that Google engineers already loading this on the tread. Double-wrapping will not be a solution here. Of course Google engineers suppose to read this forum and answer questions like this but oh well

Answer (score 10):

It's a connection problem. I fixed it by uninstalling my ad blocker...

Answer (score 3):

Simply just check all of your internet connections. My Laptop had internet while the phone hadn't. I did try to connect to the web server on my laptop and it was working fine. so after trying heaps with the phone, I rebooted my DSL router. and everything is fine and back to normal then.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when moving between networks and leaving the emulator running.

I discovered that simply restarting the emulator once I was connected to the new network solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check /etc/hosts file. Many custom roms has adblock entries ...