# Android AdMob is not displayed on real device

Tags: android, admob

AdMob is displayed correctly on emulators for android versions 2.3 and 4.2 but on real device (android version 4.0.4) it's not displayed. the error is

```
12-22 19:35:56.930: ERROR/Ads(6311): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (http://media.admob.com/:1)
12-22 19:35:56.930: ERROR/Web Console(6311): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined at http://media.admob.com/:1
```

the code is

admob_preference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center">
    <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="a150d2d17822fc0"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AdmobPreference.java

```
public class AdmobPreference extends Preference
{

    public AdmobPreference(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public AdmobPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        //override here to return the admob ad instead of a regular preference display
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.admob_preference, null);
    }

}
```

preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.nbrk.rates.AdmobPreference android:key="ad" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717358/uncaught-referenceerror-afma-getsdkconstants-is-not-defined

Comment: yeah, I've already seen that discussion. as I said there's no problem on emulators, only on real device. and there's no official info that admob should be loaded in separate thread.

Comment: the problem was in hosts file.