# AdView Code that USED to work, no longer works, 1 day later

Tags: android, admob, adview

I have no idea what's going on, with zero changes to my code, and 1 day later, I'm now getting no Admob ads being displayed (previously worked flawlessly) and I am getting this error:

```
E/Ads(775): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (http://media.admob.com/:1)
```

I am not using any code to launch ads, just XML as follows:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="<took my id out>"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

PLEASE, if anyone knows or has a hunch what could be wrong, I really appreciate some advice!

Thank you!

EDIT: Yea, turns out it was the fricken AVD! I deleted all my AVD's and it worked when I added a new one, works on everything from 2.3.3 to 4.2. Go figure.

Comment: In which device it used to work previously?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/104900/it-was-working-yesterday-i-swear-what-can-you-do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11049387/726863

Comment: It worked previously for all devices, including jelly bean. Lalit, putting the ad in a thread does nothing, also, that's not the answer for this problem. I've seen this spread around stackoverflow way too much, Google documentation DOES NOT MENTION putting AdRequests into a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Load the add in seperate thread then i think it will work as updated version's of android want to implement network operation in another thread.

You can use a thread and then load the add

```
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: NO, this separate thread stuff is non-sense. I keep seeing this on SO yet it doesn't solve anyones problem besides 1 guy.

Comment: @AutoM8R Visit this  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/104900/it-was-working-yesterday-i-swear-what-can-you-do

Comment: Yea, turns out it was the fricken AVD! I deleted all my AVD's and it worked when I added a new one, works on everything from 2.3.3 to 4.2. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined ads activity in your `Manifest` file like this

> ```
> <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
> ```

Comment: Remember, it worked yesterday perfectly.... I reloaded my production code, which works flawlessly, and now it won't work.