# admob not working with another emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob, ads

Hai guys, I just have a weird problem with admob. Integrated my app successfully on an emulator, but ads failed to show on the other emulator with the same software version check my logcat....

errors such as:

```
failed to provide provider info com.google.plus platform
Js:uncaught reference error: AFMA_getSdkConstants not defined(http:.....)
```

and then

```
AdLoader timed out after 60000ms
```

How come admob is working on one emulator and not on the other?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may arise due to network issue plz ensure you have proper network connectivity.

or you can trying invoking your ads inside a separate thread then main thread :

try this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717358/uncaught-referenceerror-afma-getsdkconstants-is-not-defined)

Comment: there is no network issue or any problem. it only shows google test ads banner, but no ads from other advertisers. and when i click on the banner it shows google ad preferences page..

Comment: sorry for late reply. yup!! because you are in test mode, and it will show you an test sample while in test mode.When you are ready to publish your application just remove 
"adrequest.addTestDevice(..YOUR TEST DEVICE..)" 
from the code and it should work fine. consult https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android